# How do you spell windey?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

sorry dumb question, but:

How do you spell "windy" as in a winding road could be described as "windy"

Not to be confuse with "the weather is windy"

Also, is there a better way I could have figured this out than posting a question on a forum?

Comment: Looked it up in a dictionary!

Comment: Actually "wind" and "wind", although pronounced differently, are already spelled the same.  Then just add "y".

Comment: Use *winding* for the road. Less confusion in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Windy roads and windy weather are spelled the same way. They just are.

Comment: While true, most people would probably use **winding** instead.

Comment: Paul McCartney did ...